# PHP: Double quote under single quote issue

Tags: php, wordpress

My problem is very basic. but i can't able to get rid out of it. I am trying to echo my post id under double quote. it giving id, but i need wrap id with double quote. I have tried many ways. but it is giving no any solution. is there any suitable way to make it solution. the code is

```
'desc' => '<input type="text" value="[nice_accor id='.$post_id.']" >'
```

Comment: Is that an array or are you trying to echo it like an array. Unclear question

Comment: no, no array, just working on wordpress metabox

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: [nice_accor id="925"] here 925 is post id

Comment: Like this? https://3v4l.org/GAoNp your question is still unclear

Comment: id is coming it is ok, but i can't able wrap id by double quote

Comment: You should edit your question, and add the expected result there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the same quote inside "some" quote by adding backslash `\` before the quote. It's called escaping the quotes. For example:

`echo "Hi, dude\"\"";`

OR

`echo 'It\'s been a long time ago';`

So, it's should be..

`'desc' => "<input type=\"text\" value=\"[nice_accor id='".$post_id."']\">"`

Comment: @NayeemHyderRiddhi nope. But, make sure you search with the same keyword before asking a new question. Cheers!